# Mac with dual display: full screen problems with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mac, multiple-monitors

If I hover over the Chrome green button (top left) and select Full Screen on my external display, my main monitor (i.e. my MacBook laptop screen) goes black and I can't see any content there.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I really want this, without "Displays have separate spaces".  Especially now with Kasm (VNC inside a web browser that supports microphone pass through), it's making my use of a Mac rather painful. I know it's possible to do this better on Mac, because VMware Horizon does it well.

Answer (score 2):

System Prefs > Mission Control
Switch on 'Displays have separate Spaces'

It may not be quite what you want but it's the 'cure' for what you asked;)

[image]

Personally, I consider it one of the very many reasons to never use fullscreen.